# java: get plain text with newline symbol from jEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I have a jEditorPane that is HTML based.
i found out that you can use:

```
String text = jEditorPane1.getDocument().getText(0, jEditorPane1.getDocument().getLength());
text = text.replaceAll("(?<!^)\n", "\n<br />");
jEditorPane1.setText("<html>" + text + "</html>");
```

by this way i got the text out of the editorpane. and when i want to put it back in the editorpane, i just replace the newline symbols with a < br />. and than put it back.

until now it is all fine. but when i got the text for the second time out of the editorpane, there are no newline symbols.

how can i keep this newline symbols?

Comment: Did you intend to grab the text from `jEditorPane` and then set the text on `jEditorPane1`?

Comment: sorry, wrote it wrong in the question. i have changed it.

Comment: What is the _content type_? "For a discussion on how newlines are handled, see [`DefaultEditorKit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html)."

Comment: content type = text/html. "i have a jeditorpane that is html based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">
```

this did the job for me. thanks to stanislavl!
i have checked how normaly a newline works in a jeditpane in html mode. it is the p tag with no margin.
strange implimentation, however it worked.

```
text = text.replaceAll("\n(.*?)(?=(\n|$))", "<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">$1</p>");
```

this does the real job. it surrounds all text after a \n with the < p>< /p> tag.

thanks for helping

Comment: I think using a <div> instead of <p> should also work without extra space between paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

TRy to use `"</p><p>"` instead of the `"<br>"` in the mid and

```
jEditorPane1.setText("<html><p>" + text + "</p></html>");
```

Comment: that works indeed. but it is not wonderfull. because i got a extra newline in the jeditorpane. however, i got 1 newline symbol back when i get the text. Is it posible to make the < p> tag only spring 1 line down instead of 2?